# React Native text span background gradient

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradient

Is there a way to wrap a background gradient around the words in a React Native text component? like this:

[image]

I've found a nice component `react-native-linear-gradient` to create the gradient and so for I have:

```
<LinearGradient
  start={[0.0, 0.25]} end={[0.5, 1.0]}
  colors={['#ED0082', '#143FCC']}
  style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

But the gradient wraps around the entire text component like this:

[image]

Comment: what's the question? seems like you already solved it.

Comment: @free-soul sorry, could have been a little clearer.. I'm looking to wrap the gradient background around the words of the text component and not the entire block.

Comment: you want gradient around words or did you mean  letters?

Comment: OP wants the gradient to stop like in the first picture. Instead it spans the full length of the second line.

Comment: Got it, sorry I din't notice that :) my eyes betrayed me. I was thinking both pics were the same.

Comment: Maybe wrapping it in a `<View>` can do the job (not sure about it)

Comment: @Chris hi! did you find a way of making this to work?